# ExecuteNonQuery() throws "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'"

Tags: c#, sql, executenonquery

I started learning C# last week and I'm now having trouble with an INSERT sql statement. I used the following code, then I tell you what happens.

```
private void AddNewUserToDataBase(User user)
{
    string commandText = "INSERT INTO User (firstName,lastName,adress,town,favoriteCurrency) " +
                         "VALUES (@firstName,@lastName,@adress,@town,@favoriteCurrency)";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(global::Laboratoire1.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = commandText;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            // je passe les paramètres ici pour éviter les erreurs au niveau du string commande 

            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@firstName", user.getFirstName())); // autre façon plus générale
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lastName", user.getLastName()));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@adress", user.getAdress()));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@town", user.getTown()));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@favoriteCurrency", user.getFavoriteCurrencyId()));

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Une erreur s'est produite.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My program do not crashes and the exception message box shows up. I've trying to understand my error and changing the syntax of my command.Parameters.Add, but it still doesn't work :/.

---

After changing the catch block to display the exception instead of swallowing it, it throws:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'

Comment: Whenever you have an exception, the exception will tell you the error.  However, you have swallowed it and just shown a generic message.  You should examine the value of `ex` and ideally *not* swallow it and either log it to a file, show the exception `.ToString()` in your message box, or both.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice, I didn't know that :).
So the problem is : "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.

I don't understand this : My table User has all those parameters and an auto incremented generated ID. I use varchars, and int for the field favoriteCurrency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a table with the name "User", but that's a [reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx).

You could rename the table, or enclose it in brackets when you reference it:

```
string commandText = "INSERT INTO [User] (firstName ...
```

Comment: It works ! Thanks a lot, kinda disappointed having an error with that :p 
You both teached me something about C#, thanks guys.

Comment: @bengous the square brackets has nothing to do with C#, that is part of SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Change the table name from "User" to something else because User is a reserved keyword that cannot be used again, so if you use any other name for table the code will work fine example:-

```
create table User1(firstName varchar(20),lastName varchar(20),adress varchar(20),town varchar(20),favoriteCurrency int)
```